# How to get start date and end date of a week from given year and week?

Tags: javascript

```
function getWeekDate(year, week) {
  var obj = {
    2017:["12/26~01/01","01/02~01/08","01/09~01/15","01/16~01/22","01/23~01/29","01/30~02/05","02/06~02/12","02/13~02/19","02/20~02/26","02/27~03/05","03/06~03/12","03/13~03/19","03/20~03/26","03/27~04/02","04/03~04/09","04/10~04/16","04/17~04/23","04/24~04/30","05/01~05/07","05/08~05/14","05/15~05/21","05/22~05/28","05/29~06/04","06/05~06/11","06/12~06/18","06/19~06/25","06/26~07/02","07/03~07/09","07/10~07/16","07/17~07/23","07/24~07/30","07/31~08/06","08/07~08/13","08/14~08/20","08/21~08/27","08/28~09/03","09/04~09/10","09/11~09/17","09/18~09/24","09/25~10/01","10/02~10/08","10/09~10/15","10/16~10/22","10/23~10/29","10/30~11/05","11/06~11/12","11/13~11/19","11/20~11/26","11/27~12/03","12/04~12/10","12/11~12/17","12/18~12/24","12/25~12/31"],
    2018:["01/01~01/07","01/08~01/14","01/15~01/21","01/22~01/28","01/29~02/04","02/05~02/11","02/12~02/18","02/19~02/25","02/26~03/04","03/05~03/11","03/12~03/18","03/19~03/25","03/26~04/01","04/02~04/08","04/09~04/15","04/16~04/22","04/23~04/29","04/30~05/06","05/07~05/13","05/14~05/20","05/21~05/27","05/28~06/03","06/04~06/10","06/11~06/17","06/18~06/24","06/25~07/01","07/02~07/08","07/09~07/15","07/16~07/22","07/23~07/29","07/30~08/05","08/06~08/12","08/13~08/19","08/20~08/26","08/27~09/02","09/03~09/09","09/10~09/16","09/17~09/23","09/24~09/30","10/01~10/07","10/08~10/14","10/15~10/21","10/22~10/28","10/29~11/04","11/05~11/11","11/12~11/18","11/19~11/25","11/26~12/02","12/03~12/09","12/10~12/16","12/17~12/23","12/24~12/30"],
    2019:["12/31~01/06"]
  }
  return obj[year][week - 1]
}
```

For example here I can get all the weeks in 2017, 2018, and the first week of 2019. Of course I could list all the weeks in a year and then get the date off that array but it seems very inefficient. What other methods I could use to get the start date and the end date of a week from given year and week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.proesite.com/timex/wkcalc.htm) week definition, you could calculate the week range by:

```
function getDateOfWeek(year, week) {
    var start = (1 + (week - 1) * 7); // 1st of January + 7 days for each week
    var end = 6 + start; // add 6 more days to get the end of the week

    return {start: new Date(year, 0, start), end: new Date(year, 0, end)};
}
```

However, following your week definition, you could probably done something like this

```
function weekDateToDate (year, week) {
    var firstDayOfYear = new Date(year, 0, 1)
    var start = 2 + (week - 1) * 7 - firstDayOfYear.getDay();
    var end = start + 6;
    return {start: new Date(year, 0, start), end: new Date(year, 0, end)};
}
```

Comment: so this code is referring to week starting on Monday @Andreas?